# Declaration of child method must be compatible with parent method

Tags: php

Here's my code :

I have a class `A`, with a method `foo`, that returns a `Bar` object.

```
class A {
    public function foo(): Bar {
        //some ops
        return $bar; //'Bar' object
    }
}
```

I also have a class `B`, that extends class `A`, with an overridden method `foo`, that returns a `BarX` object.

```
class B extends A {
    public function foo(): BarX {
        //some ops
        return $barX; //'BarX' object
    }
}
```

What is important is that **the `BarX` class extends the `Bar` class**.

When I run my code, I have an error on class `B`, saying :

> Declaration of `B::foo(): BarX` must be compatible with `A::foo(): Bar`

How are they not compatible since `BarX` extends `Bar` ? And how could I fix this problem please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider: `function (A $a) { $b = $a->foo(); }` – is `$b` a `Bar` or a `BarX`? You don't know. Arguably, if both types are compatible, it doesn't matter. But you should simply not have such vagaries in your type system.

Comment: @deceze : Yes I do.
`$b` is a `Bar`, since `$a` is a `A` object, and the `foo` method of `A` objects returns `Bar` objects. There is no `B` object in your example, how could `$b` be a `BarX` object ?

Comment: Since `B` is a subclass of `A` the caller can also inject a `B` for `$a`!

Comment: @deceze I understand :), so I think having both `foo` functions returning a `Bar` is the best solution, thank you

Comment: I was just in the process of writing this up as an answer… :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a BarX but since B extends A, it must return the same type but since BarX is Bar, you can do it like that:

```
class B extends A {
    public function foo(): Bar {
        $barX = new BarX;
        //some ops
        return $barX; //'BarX' object
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I think I will not have any choice but doing so

Answer (score 2):

Have both Bar and BarX implement an interface and have that as you're return type.

```
<?php 

interface BarInterface(){ }

class Bar implements BarInterface(){ }

class BarX implements BarInterface(){ }

class A {
    public function foo(): BarInterface {
        //some ops
        return $bar; //'Bar' object
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo(): BarInterface {
        //some ops
        return $barX; //'BarX' object
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Goon3r, but actually this means _both_ `A::foo()` and `B::foo()` methods can return either `Bar` or `BarX` objects. That is equevalent to having :
`A::foo(): **Bar**` and
`B::foo(); **Bar**`
...which makes the interface useless, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Study the [L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) carefully and consider:

```
function (A $a) {
    $bar = $a->foo();
}
```

Is `$bar` going to be a `Bar` or `BarX`? You don't know. Since `$a` can be injected either as an `A` or `B` (because `B instanceof A`, because `B extends A`), you can't predict what `$a` will be and hence what `$bar` will be.

That's why a uniform and predictable interface is important and that's what PHP complains about.